# How to extract weights of DQN agent in TF-Agents framework?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, transfer-learning, dqn

I am using TF-Agents for a custom reinforcement learning problem, where I train a DQN (constructed using DqnAgents from the TF-Agents framework) on some features from my custom environment, and separately use a keras convolutional model to extract these features from images. Now I want to combine these two models into a single model and use transfer learning, where I want to initialize the weights of the first part of the network (images-to-features) as well as the second part which would have been the DQN layers in the previous case.

I am trying to build this combined model using keras.layers and compiling it with the Tf-Agents tf.networks.sequential class to bring it to the necessary form required when passing it to the DqnAgent() class. (Let's call this statement (a)).

I am able to initialize the image feature extractor network's layers with the weights since I saved it as a .h5 file and am able to obtain numpy arrays of the same. So I am able to do the transfer learning for this part.

The problem is with the DQN layers, where I saved the policy from the previous example using the prescribed Tensorflow Saved Model Format (pb) which gives me a folder containing model attributes. However, I am unable to view/extract the weights of my DQN in this way, and the recommended tf.saved_model.load('policy_directory') is not really transparent with respect to what data I can see regarding the policy. If I have to follow the transfer learning as I do in statement (a), I need to extract the weights of my DQN and assign them to the new network. The documentation seems to be quite sparse for this case where transfer learning needs to be applied.

Can anyone help me in this, by explaining how I can extract weights from the Saved Model method (from the pb file)? Or is there a better way to go about this problem?

Comment: Any updates on your problem?

Comment: I added a method in the dqn_agent.py script in the tf-agents package to return weights of the q-network and the target network as NumPy arrays. However, I haven't put that in other agents and it is not a tf-agents approved technique.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add to this another solution, as I found myself in a similar situation:

I want to train a DQN Agent in a standard DQN fashion for Atari Breakout, however, I want to monitor the weights during training in regular intervals. I use the DqnAgent() class and give it a QNetwork() instance for the 'q_network' argument.

One way to achieve this, is like you Tarun Sriram said, to directly modify the source code of the DqnAgent() class, namely the 'dqn_agent.py' file, by adding a method like:

```
def get_q_network_weights(self):
    # get weights and biases as numpy arrays
    weights = self._q_network.trainable_weights[-2].numpy()
    biases  = self._q_network.trainable_weights[-1].numpy()
    # get weights and biases as tensorflow tensors
    weights = tf.identity(self._q_network.trainable_weights[-2])
    biases = tf.identity(self._q_network.trainable_weights[-1])
    return weights, biases
```

Note that you have to use tf.identity() to create a deep copy, otherwise only a reference to the original tensor will be returned and thus it will change during training (meaning if I happen to store the weights in a list during training, in the end all values would be the same as they point to the same original tensor).

There is, however, a less intrusive method: You can directly access the weights (and biases) of the Q-Network you pass to the DQN Agent constructor. In my example the Q-Network I pass is simply called "q_net":

```
agent = DqnAgent(..., q_network=q_net, ...)
```

Now during training, you can simply use:

```
q_net.trainable_weights
```

or (for specific layer weights):

```
q_net.get_layer("name_of_layer").get_weights()
```

Note that also here you should either directly convert the returned tensor to a numpy array or create a deep copy using tf.identity() in order to avoid having multiple copies of the same reference.